# Windows 7 Network using different user

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-xp, user

following problem: I have a windows 7 box and alot of xp boxes. Every xp box supplies a network drive. But my windows 7 box signs in with some user that has not got any privileges.

Can I set a default network user in Windows 7? So my 7 box doesn't use my local username but the username I configured somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: That's a question for ServerFault.com

Comment: Franz Kafka! I love your work.

Comment: This question is off-topic on this site, but you don't have to do anything. It will be automatically migrated to a more suitable location shortly. I'd post an answer anyway, but I've recently been lambasted for doing that on off-topic questions. The simple solution is to explicitly map the network resource as a drive. When doing so, Windows will prompt you to enter a specific set of credentials to use.